# grep -E-f to capture matching ip-addresses in two files, and , print or echo result of each iteration, xx.xx.xx.xx found or xx.xx.xx.xx not found

Tags: bash, shell-script, grep

Having one short list of few hundred ip addresses in `file1`,  and want to identify if any of these ip addresses are missing from the master list, `file2`.
Looking for an output > redirect to a file that prints result of both cases like:

```
xx.xx.xx.xx missing
xx.xx.xx.xx found
```

Already reviewed a half dozen similar questions and learned a lot but none of existing questions quite answers my problem, so I've created my own Q.

I've tried a few approaches both using `awk`, as well as `grep -F -f` but having trouble reconciling the result of the compare, and building the logical statement.

Already reviewed a half dozen existing answers and learned a lot but none addressed my objective quite in the way I understand it.

Answer (score 1):

With a while loop:

```
while IFS= read -r i; do
  grep -Fq "$i" file && echo "$i found" || echo "$i missing"
done <ip_addresses
```

---

- `while` loops trough each line in the file `ip_addresses`

  - `grep -Fq` searches for lines containing matches from the fixed string (`-F`), that the dot doesn't match any character. The `-q` flag forces `grep` to print nothing.
  - `&& echo "$i found"` if `grep` succeeds the address is found.
  - `|| echo "$i missing"` if not, it's missing

Comment: I may be missing a clue, but assuming that "ip_addresses"  is the filename containing the "unknown" list at hand, I don't see where the lines from the reference file which contains the motherload gets read into the buffer.  **am I missing something in your script?**

Comment: _The way I thought it might work is if the reference motherload is read into buffer and stored in one variable,_ like:  `M="$(awk '{print $1}' master)" `   _then the  **unknown list* of ip addresses are read into another variable as you've shown.  Then a conditional structure has to validate when  `$i  ==  $M` and print or echo `"$i found"` exactly as you shown, or else  `|| echo "$i missing"`   This is the part I have difficulty with as I've put together several ways, none work!

Comment: @user2793091 I don't understand what you mean. The file called `file` is your master list. The file `ip_adresses` contains the list you want to search in the file `file`. If the ip is found it shoud print "ip found", else it should print "ip missing". That's what my script does. `grep` does the comparsion and its exit value desides what to print.

Comment: **YES YES, it works!** penny dropped!  I failed to see what you were doing because I overlooked *file" and didn't register it verbose as the filename of unknown addresses.  I just tried your solution and works fine against both a clean file where non-ip address txt is removed,  as well as the raw file with all kinds of comment lines.  **Thank you**   I'll close this question in a couple of days while I study the alternate solutions.

Comment: @user2793091 You're welcome, but closing the question after getting an answer is not the site works here. Please read http://unix.stackexchange.com/tour

Answer (score 0):

Assume file `l1` is the list with the unknown IP addresses and file `l2` is the master list.

The following will list all IP addresses that are only in `l1` and not in `l2`:

```
egrep -v "`cat l2|xargs -I {} echo -n '|{}'|sed -e 's/^|//'`" l1
```

If you remove option `-v` then it will list all IP address that occur in `l1` and `l2`:

```
egrep "`cat l2|xargs -I {} echo -n '|{}'|sed -e 's/^|//'`" l1
```

Both files `l1` and `l2` must be in the same format.

The following command:

```
cat l2|xargs -I {} echo -n '|{}'|sed -e 's/^|//'
```

creates a list of IP addresses, separated by `|`, from the content of file `l2`. The `|` is the `or` character for the regex that is passed to `egrep`.

Tested with files:

```
$ cat l1
192.168.0.10
192.168.2.14
192.168.0.11
192.168.0.9

$ cat l2
10.64.10.200
192.168.4.0
192.168.2.3
192.168.0.10
192.168.0.11
192.168.1.0
192.168.2.0
```

Find missing IP addresses:

```
$ egrep -v "`cat l2|xargs -I {} echo -n '|{}'|sed -e 's/^|//'`" l1
192.168.2.14
192.168.0.9
```

Find duplicate IP addresses:

```
$ egrep  "`cat l2|xargs -I {} echo -n '|{}'|sed -e 's/^|//'`" l1
192.168.0.10
192.168.0.11
```

I only hope that your files are not too long to overflow the maximum command line length :-(

Comment: _Thanks, its's amazing that you've done in one line what might take me a paragraph of code to do, and still not work.  I should have started this when I was much younger!  Anyway, I tried running your solution both on command line, as well as in a bash script and both times nothing happens, cursor goes blank and won't respond to kbd except for when I press_ CNTL C_

Comment: @user2793091 I've checked the commands with 2048 IP addresses in file `l1` and 3584 IP addresses in file `l2`. That takes 4 seconds on my machine. If I increase file `l2` to 14336 IP addresses, it takes 10s to complete. If your files are longer or you have a slow machine, it will take even longer.  Are you sure you copied all the quotes and back-ticks correctly? Have you tried with short files? E.g. the ones I gave in my example. If you replace `grep` with `echo` you should see all IP addresses of file `l2` separated by `|`.